# Can one execute custom C++ code and write to disk?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

There are some C++ executable (and sometimes source code that I need to compile into an executable) that I would like to call for my Java dataflow code. Is that possible? If so, how do I go about installing and possibly compiling the C++ code onto the virtual machines that dataflow uses, and how do I inform dataflow to use those specific virtual machines? Furthermore, can my Java code  write to disc if it needs to (e.g. there are some incredibly large objects that may not be able to be stored in RAM, and so I temporally need to store it to disk while I do some processing). (Normally, I do know that one should rewrite the code in the Google cloud dataflow distributed architecture, but in certain circumstances, it's just “easier” in the short term and for specific use cases just to write to disk because certain libraries are already written etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to execute other binaries or use JNI to invoke C++ code from Dataflow.  You can use the [--filesToStage](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/7823ced57b3e5806e2c4ea19fda43744d1d70b04/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/options/DataflowPipelineWorkerPoolOptions.java#L241) option to stage any files you want to the worker VMs, and then use them however you'd like from the workers.  You'll need to include all jars you need to run your Java code as well in the list you pass to --filesToStage.

The workers all have disks, so you can use that as well.  Do be aware that there are no guarantees about how long any particular worker will exist, so the disks are only guaranteed to be around for a single bundle.  Since you only need to temporarily buffer the data, this should be ok for you.